# Symfony force login and remember me

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

Following code will force login user automatically and it works fine. I want to add remember me functionality. So when we force login user and then also add ***remember me***, so next time he automatically login to the site.

```
// Auto Authenticate User
        $firewall = 'user_firewall';
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewall, $user->getRoles());
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

        $session = $this->get('session');
        $session->set('_security_'.$firewall, serialize($token));
        $session->save();
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html

Comment: need to remember me without form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RemeberMeToken and there is no need to set it manually in session, just fire interactive_login event:

```
// Auto Authenticate User
$firewall = 'user_firewall';
$key = $this->getParameter('secret'); //from parameters.yml
$token = new RememberMeToken($user, $firewall, $key);
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

$this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(
    SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN,
    new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token)
);
```

EDIT:
add this to your security.yml:

```
        yourProviderKey: # oauth i guess
            remember_me: true
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /
            #always_remember_me: true # optional
```

If this will not work, try to add `?_remember_me=1` to the end of your `check_path`.

Comment: Wow, this looks simple compare to other solutions I found.  How can I verify if this is working correctly?

Comment: The above code does not set cookie `REMEMBERME`, but if I login using form and set remember me, then it set cookie fine. so above code is not working!